# Is there any haproxy development guide?

Tags: load-balancing, development-environment, haproxy

Isn't that weird that Haproxy doesn't have any development guide to start for a beginner? For instance, for the university, I have to modify HA, but most of the content I do find on the internet is configurations of haproxy, but how to start developing it, I can't find any references.
Maybe someone knows where to get that information? Even though there are summaries on almost every method in their repo, but it still would be better if there was a more broad explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy

> The more detailed documentation is located into the doc/ directory :
>
> - doc/intro.txt for a quick introduction on HAProxy
> - doc/configuration.txt for the configuration's reference manual
> - doc/lua.txt for the Lua's reference manual
> - doc/SPOE.txt for how to use the SPOE engine
> - doc/network-namespaces.txt for how to use network namespaces under Linux
> - doc/management.txt for the management guide
> - doc/regression-testing.txt for how to use the regression testing suite
> - doc/peers.txt for the peers protocol reference
> - doc/coding-style.txt for how to adopt HAProxy's coding style
> - doc/internals for developer-specific documentation (not all up to date)

maybe you wanna start at `doc/internals`